# Make a calendar starting on a specified day of the week

Tags: java, for-loop, calendar

Ok, so I am trying to make a calendar that allows the user to input both the day that the first Monday is of the month and the total number of days in the month.

*The output should look something like this:*
(See linked image)

[IMAGE](http://i.imgur.com/h7437DU.png)

*This is what I have so far:*

```
int daysLeft = numDays;

for(int week = 1; week <= 5; week++)
     {
        if(daysLeft > 1)
        {
           for(int day = 1; day <= numDays; day++)
           {
              if((day % 7) == 1) , if the day % 7 (a week) is equal to 1 then go to the next line
              {
                 System.out.println();
              }

              System.out.print(day); 
              daysLeft--; 
           }
        }
     }
```

I want to use nested-for loops for this, I know it can be done and I know I could use the calendar class but I am learning and would like to use for loops. So, the above code works **if** the first Monday is also the fist day.

With all that out of the way, based on the above info, how can I make a way using for loops to change the starting position of the month?

**Edit**
Ignore leap years.

Comment: You also have to worry about leap years (February could have 28 or 29 days).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Lets say for the sake of simplicity we ignore leap years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You probably don't need a nested for loop, your outer-for loop did nothing actually

2) I am still a bit unclear ab your requirements, this is the best I could come up and I think it does what you described nicely:

```
public static void printCalendar(int monday, int numDays) {
    if (monday > 7 || monday < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid monday.");
    if (numDays > 31 || numDays < 1 || numDays < monday) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid numDays.");

    System.out.print("Mon\t");
    System.out.print("Tue\t");
    System.out.print("Wed\t");
    System.out.print("Thur\t");
    System.out.print("Fri\t");
    System.out.print("Sat\t");
    System.out.print("Sun\t");
    System.out.println();

    int padding = (7 - (monday - 1)) % 7;

    for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
        System.out.print(" \t");
    }

    for (int day = 1; day <= numDays; day++) {
        if ((padding + day) % 7 == 0)
            System.out.println(day + "\t");
        else
            System.out.print(day + "\t");
    }
}
```

[sample output with printCalendar(3, 31);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MffOa.png)

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Very cleaver, thank you.